# What is iTunes App Store ID field for?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, itunes

I'm setting up an iPhone app which integrates with Facebook.

The app's settings in the facebook developer page are asking for "iTunes App Store ID"... is this the number in the url for the app? So the number would be 430671660 for this app:...?

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/craigslist-mobile-ultimate/id430671660?mt=8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer it should be.  If you want to verify go its under your apps information in itunesconnect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that ID is correct. The ID is the ID Generated for the App Store in iTunes Connect.